# Visual studio 2013: cursor lagging while debugger hits the breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, breakpoints

In our company me and some of my colleagues switched from windows 7 do windows 10. All of us noticed the same bug in the  Visual Studio 2013:
When the debugger hits the breakpoint and stay there, writing a text starts annoyingly lag anywhere (e.g. in visual studio, notepad, browser...). Everything else on PC works without lagging.
I also have noticed that it happens only if we debug the application which extensively use the GPU.

P.S. Yes we have an updated drivers for Nvidia.